# AutoCompleteTextView not returning text for Android 6.0+

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` that has worked correctly and still works correctly for all devices under 6.0.

I call `getText().toString()` and I get the text.

But on Android 6.0+ it returns an empty string.

The `AutoCompleteTextView` itself is working fine besides this. Still shows hint text, still shows the dropdown suggestions, etc.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?